# Web page on Vagrant is not updating when I edit the file

Tags: nginx, vagrant

I have the file on the *Vagrant* named *index.html*, and config the nginx a web server vhost like `my.loc`, the index.html can access in chrome on my Mac, which the vagrant's host.
Now the problem is :
when I edit the index.html file such as

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title11</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and then I change the `title11` to `title22`, the web page not change on the chrome.
So first I think it's the cache problem, and I config the nginx.conf like this to forbid the cache :

```
location ~.*\.(js|css|html|png|jpg)$
{
    #expires    -1;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
}
```

it doesn't work. However, I found that if I run the cmd `touch /myweb/index.html` on the vagrant, the web page changes on Chrome, but it's not what I want.

EDIT:
this is my nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /vagrant/nginx-error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /vagrant/nginx-access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /vagrant/nginx-vhosts/*.conf;
}
```

Now I found if I edit the index.html on linux in the vagrant, and then the page will change on chrome in my Mac OS.So I think the problem is about vagrant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve the problem to change `sendfile on` to `sendfile off` in the nginx.conf.

I get the answer from this article : [Clear nginx Cache in Vagrant](https://jeremyfelt.com/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant/)

This is because:

> Sendfile is used to ‘copy data between one file descriptor and another‘ and apparently has some real trouble when run in a virtual machine environment, or at least when run through Virtualbox. Turning this config off in nginx causes the static file to be served via a different method and your changes will be reflected immediately and without question